# How to use the same key of dictionary but different value for build the graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

How to build a new graph based on the key order from the previous graph.
This is my coding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from maxTPRlist import *
from max1TPRlist import *
from collections import OrderedDict
```

The previous graph

```
plt.figure('FPR=0,TPR=?')
plt.title('FPR=0,TPR=?')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate(TPR)')
plt.xlabel('KO Files')
plt.ylim(ymax = 1.0000, ymin = 0.000)
plt.grid(True)

# I sort following the value
d_descending = OrderedDict(sorted(mTPRlist.items(),
                                  key=lambda (k,v): (v,k), reverse=True))

plt.plot(range(len(d_descending)), d_descending.values(), label="FPR=0,TPR=?", marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.xticks(range(len(d_descending)), list(d_descending.keys()), rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The new graph

```
plt.figure('FPR=1%,TPR=?')
plt.title('FPR=1%,TPR=?')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate(TPR)')
plt.xlabel('KO Files')
plt.ylim(ymax = 1.0000, ymin = 0.000)
plt.grid(True)

## I take the key from previous for x-axis and it sorted in the same way.
## But the order of value for y-axis is mistaken.
plt.plot(range(len(d_descending)), m1TPRlist.values(), label="FPR=1%,TPR=?", marker='o', linestyle='-', color='g')
plt.xticks(range(len(d_descending)), list(d_descending.keys()), rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is example my data.

```
mTPRlist={'K00855': '0.991', 'K02446': '0.762', 'K01689': '0.957', 'K03712': '0.974', 'K01622': '0.961'}
mTPRlist={'K00855': '0.992', 'K02446': '0.255', 'K01689': '0.151', 'K03712': '0.950', 'K01622': '0.187'}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me: do you want to sort `mList` based on its values, and then apply the new order of keys from `mList` to `mTPRlist`?

Comment: Yes I want to sort the **mList** based on its value. But not apply new order of keys just stick with the same position and add the value of **mTPRlist**.